# Desktop menu disappear, characters are difficult to be inserted from the keyboards, menus flicker, win start menu difficult to pop up

Tags: laptop

I have series of problems such as:

- When I begin to log on to my computer, the characters are difficult to enter.
- When I right click on the desktop, menu disappears.
- Wlso, when I double click on a file or folder, the properties dialog box opens.
- The menus on the window including the window and everything in it just keep flickering
- When I click on one of the menus, it just disappear.
- Also the start button does not work constantly. for this I need your help

I am using:
win 8.1 and up to date
HP Pavillion dv9000
1.9GB RAM
64bit

Comment: check if your "Alt" button is stuck

Comment: It doesn't seem to be stucked

Comment: How exactly did you check? I would recommend removing the key and making sure that you clean the contacts properly. If that does not help, you can try another keyboard

Comment: However it does seem to be stucked looking at the on screen keyboard

Comment: OK I will as you recommended

Comment: Or simply disconnect the keyboard when you're seeing this behavior. Give the PC a moment and see if the behavior stops. That's a sure sign of a keyboard problem.

Answer (score 0):

All symptoms you have described are typical for stuck <kbd>Alt</kbd> button.

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `mouse click` on the file opens `Properties` window
- Constantly pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> makes context menu disappear immediately after right click
- Constantly stuck <kbd>Alt</kbd> makes explorer menus disappear immediately after left click, producing just a brief flicker

I would recommend you to remove the key and clean up the contacts of <kbd>Alt</kbd> button. For that refer to your computer's service manual or watch some howto videos on YouTube.

If cleaning contacts does not help - consider replacing the keyboard.